# Liquid storage of transition metal oxides?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, transition-metals, oxides

Transition metal oxides (TMOs) have a lot of interesting properties, from ferroelectricity to battery applications. Often times you can change the properties with only slight changes of oxygen stoichiometry. For example, SrTiO$_3$ is an insulating paramagnet, but becomes ferroelectric and then metallic with slight changes in oxygen stoichiometry in SrTiO$_{3+\delta}$. Another example is La$_2$CuO$_4$ which is an insulator, but with increasing oxygen content La$_2$CuO$_{4+\delta}$ becomes a superconducting metal.

One downside of this functionality is that transition metal oxides are notoriously finicky, and tend to change properties upon exposure to air, moisture, etc. In many cases, bulk polycrystals of TMOs have to stored under inert gases or vacuum to maintain their properties. Needless to say, that is quite annoying with regards to transportation.

My question is: **is it possible to store transition metal oxides in liquids without significant deterioration?** If so, which ones are the most practical? I'm sure the answer is "it depends", but even general suggestions and publication references would be useful.